# Get Session from SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute to SignalR.Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working on a SignalR.Hub and I have custom Authorization in an SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute. I have been trying to pass the session I have to retrieve to confirm the User is Authenticated to use the Hub.

I've looked through all of the properties and it seems that they are mostly read-only. I can add something to SignalR.IRequest.Environment but it doesn't appear to be thread-safe and seems improper.

Could I extend the HubCallerContext + Everything that uses it in a way I can tack on my session?

The custom auth

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class HubAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        return VerifySession(request);
    }

    public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
    {
        //Could I add something to the HubIncomingInvokerContext?
        return VerifySession(hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Request);
    }

    public bool VerifySession(IRequest request)
    {
        bool success = false;
        string token = "";
        bool isApiToken = false;

        // Check for token Header Auth
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            token = request.QueryString["X-Custom-Token"];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                token = request.QueryString["X-Custom-Token"];
                isApiToken = true;
            }
        }

        SessionResponse session = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            session = isApiToken ? ValidateApiToken(token) : ValidateToken(token);
        }

        if (session != null)
        {
            //Add Session to request! So I dont have to hit the db again..
            //request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("session", session));
            success = true;
        }
        return success;
    }

    //... other methods that aren't relevant
}
```

The Hub

```cs
[HubAuthorize]
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Use the session here
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

Why have custom authorization if you cant use that to retrieve a session when you verify you are authenticated? Maybe I'm missing something but its pretty frustrating. /endrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you can't. I still verify the session in HubAuthorize.AuthorizeHubConnection, then in the NotificationHub.OnConnected I build a dictionary of Context.ConnectionId as the key and retrieve the session a secondary time for the value. Feels hackish but there doesn't seem to be a good way to prevent people from accessing the hub without using the .Net built in auth.